# Python socket how to listen on hostname instead of ip address

Tags: python, sockets, server, client

So in my server side i am open the `socket`:

```
host = '192.168.0.20'
port = 9999
socket = socket.socket()
socket.bind((host, port))
socket.listen(5)
```

And from `client` side:

```
socket = socket.socket()
host = '192.168.0.20'
port = 9999
socket.connect((host, port))
```

Now because i want my `server` to be more generic so instead of specify the `ip address` i try to do it this way:

```
host=socket.gethostname()
```

And from my `client` just connect to my host name.
But unfortunately this is now working.

Any suggestions ?

Comment: why not socket.gethostbyname(socket.gethostname()) ?

Comment: socket.gethostbyname(socket.gethostname()) from client side ?

Comment: The problem is that because my machine have several network card so one of them this is the real ip affress and other like 169.254.x.x and sometimes your code return this fake ip address and not the real one

Comment: ok, whats the error you are getting with socket.connect((host, port))
 ?

Comment: Probably, so how can i fix it ?